# Were the commentaries and subcommentaries part of the Tang Code?

Tags: china, medieval-china

Are the commentaries and subcommentaries in Wallace Johnson's translation of the Tang Code (Princeton University Press) written by Wallace Johnson or are they part of the original text of the Code?

Answer (score 1):

[The publisher](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691636320/the-tang-code-volume-ii) describes this as "an annotated translation", which normally means that there are notes by the translator. [Another source](http://lsc.chineselegalculture.org/Documents/E-Library?ID=8) consistent with this: "The translation as well as the abundant annotations are to be praised for their remarkable erudition and relevance."